# C++11 safely join a thread without using a try / catch block

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, exception

According to the documentation [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable), the join method of a C++11 thread will throw a `std::system_error` if `joinable() == false`. Thus the natural way to wait for a thread to complete execution is something along the lines of:

```
if (thread2.joinable()) thread2.join();
```

However, this has the possibility to throw a std::system_error. Consider thread 1 calls thread2.joinable(), returns true, indicating that the thread2 is still running. Then the scheduler pauses thread1 and switches contexts to thread 2. Thread 2 completes, and then thread 1 resumes. Thread 1 calls thread2.join(), but thread2 has already completed, and as a result, std::system_error is thrown.

A possible solution is to wrap the whole thing in a try block:

```
try {
    thread2.join();
catch (std::system_error &e) {}
```

But then when a legitimate std::system_error is thrown, possibly to indicate that the thread **failed to join**, the program continues on, acting as though everything is fine and dandy. Is there a proper way to join a thread besides using a try/catch block like this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`joinable` does not do what you think it does. *All* it does is return whether the thread object is not associated with a thread. However, `thread::join` will fail if the thread object also represents the current thread. So the only reason for `thread::join` to fail due to lack of `joinable` is if you tried to join with yourself.

A *completed* thread (which isn't your own) is still perfectly joinable.

Comment: `joinable` will also return `false` if the thread is detached.

Comment: @Adam: Thanks for clarifying what "not associated with a thread" really means.

Comment: `return whether the thread object represents the current thread or is not associated with a thread` [joinable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable) checks **only** association with a thread, but not with the current thread. **But** [join](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) will check current thread and report `system_error`. [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/422f27866296efd0) example.