# Thread joining issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety

I was reading some [manuals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) about threads and I've come to a thought that the code they show is not safe:

```
std::cout << "starting first helper...\n";
std::thread helper1(foo);

std::cout << "starting second helper...\n";
std::thread helper2(bar);

std::cout << "waiting for helpers to finish..." << std::endl;
helper1.join();   // #1 NOT SAFE
helper2.join();   // #2 NOT SAFE
```

I believe this code is not absolutely safe. If I am not mistaking there is no guarantee that `helper1` and `helper2` are already in joinable state when control reaches lines marked as `#1` and `#2`. Threads could still be not launched and have no ids at this point. Which will cause an uncaught exception being thrown from `std::thread::join()`

I think the following code fixes the problem. Am I right?

```
std::cout << "starting first helper...\n";
std::thread helper1(foo);

std::cout << "starting second helper...\n";
std::thread helper2(bar);

std::cout << "waiting for helpers to finish..." << std::endl;
while ( helper1.joinable() == false ) { }
helper1.join();   // #1 SAFE
while ( helper2.joinable() == false ) { }
helper2.join();   // #2 SAFE
```

Comment: Can't the thread be joinable, even if it's not started? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994650/c11-safely-join-a-thread-without-using-a-try-catch-block

Comment: @doctorlove `std::thread::joinable return true if the thread object identifies an active thread of execution, false otherwise`. I think it can not.

Comment: what are you quoting from?

Comment: @doctorlove http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable And turns out that `active` means `scheduled` too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `std::thread` is `joinable` if it contains a thread state that has not been `join`ed or `detatch`ed.

A `std::thread` gains a thread state by being non default constructed, or having one `move`ed into it from another `std::thread`.  It loses it when `move`ed from.

There is no delay in gaining the thread state after construction completes.  And it does not go away when the threaded function finishes.  So there is not that problem.

There is the problem that if code throws above, you will fail to `join` or `detatch`, leading to bad news at program shutdown.  Always wrap `std::thread` in a RAII wrapper to avoid that, or just use `std::async` that returns `void` and wrap the resulting `std::future` similarly (because the standard says it blocks in the dtor, but microsofts implementation does not, so you cannot trust if it will or not).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not have an access to the standard at the moment. Did you quote the standard or where can I read more about the topic?

Comment: In VC `std::futures` from `std::async` don't block in dtor?

Comment: @bamboon Yup, that's true. Tested it myself.

Comment: @Kolyunya no, not a quote from the standard.  Here is a (perfectly legal) link to a working draft of the next standard: http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3797.pdf ...  From the standard, failure to `join` or `detatch` a thread causes `std::terminate`, the "run code" `std::thread` ctor has a postcondition of `get_id() != id()`, which is equivalent to `joinable()==true`.

Comment: Isn't there a typo in the comment `get_id() != id()`? Did you mean `==`? I don't get it otherwise.

Comment: @kolyunya `std::thread::id` is the type of a thread id.  `std::thread::id()` is the default constructed thread id, which is the invalid one.  `get_id() != id()` means "the `std::thread`'s thread id is not the default constructed thread id, and hence valid".

Comment: Thank you for an explanation! The most important information in your answer is that one of the postconditions of the thread nondefault ctor is that the thread is joinable. Thank you!

Comment: @ruslo 30.3.1.3.1 -- it is pretty explicit.  Not 'failure during', but 'failure to call', as in 'not calling'.

Answer (score 3):

You are perceiving threads in an overly complicated way.  `join` is there to safely *join* a thread.  Just use:

```
std::thread my_thread(my_main);
my_thread.join();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `std::thread::thread(F&& f, Args&&... args)` constructor has this postcondition:

> *Postconditions:* `get_id() != id()`. `*this` represents the newly started thread.

The definition of `joinable()` is

> *Returns:* `get_id() != id()`

Therefore the constructor's postcondition is that the object is joinable, and the postcondition applies as soon as the constructor completes.  It is irrelevant whether the OS has actually started the thread yet, the `thread` object still knows the new thread's ID and can still wait for it to complete and join it.